# log4j adds "sg" to each logged line

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

First time using log4j. 
I did not set up a log4j.properties file, since the logs are being written to different folders with every restart. I'm aware I could change the properties file at runtime, perhaps going to implement that later.

So my whole configuration is this now:

```
private static Logger createLogger(){
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
    PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %msg%n");
    logger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(layout));
    FileAppender logFileAppender = null;
    try {
        logFileAppender = new FileAppender(layout, getLogFile(), true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(2);
    }
    logger.addAppender(logFileAppender);
    return logger;
}
```

Which gives me such lines with "sg" in the end:

```
10:04:21.854 [main] System: Activated Botsg
```

How can I avoid "sg"?

OpenJDK 11,
Intellij 19.3,
Windows 10 1903
Latest log4j from mvn repositories

Comment: You have an extra `sg` in your pattern (`%msg` should be `%m`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove sg

```
PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %msg%n");
```

to

```
PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %m%n");
```

Comment: Haha awsome dude, thought its short for "message".

Comment: Fun fact, `%msg` is actually the valid conversion word for Logback (not Log4j): http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#message

Answer (score 1):

There is no Conversion Character defined as `msg` in [Apache Pattern Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)

The correct pattern should be :

```
PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %m%n");
```

> `m` is decoded as: Used to output the application supplied message
>   associated with the logging event.
>
> `n` is decoded as: This conversion character offers practically the
>   same performance as using non-portable line separator strings such as
>   "\n", or "\r\n". Thus, it is the preferred way of specifying a line
>   separator.

The extra **sg** is coming due to your incorrect character **msg**. The logger is able to decode **m** but fails the **sg** part of **msg** and thus you are getting *sg* appended at every log.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborated comment, I'll upvote this!